Working with Fuzzy Membership to select a subset of a slope raster - Gaussian Membership and spread
I have never worked with Fuzzy Membership before and am struggling to choose a membership type and spread for my analysis.
I am working with DEMs from the 30-meter SRTM Tile Downloader. I am using this StoryMap to help with site selection, but with different parameters. One of my parameters is a slope of 16 or less (road grade). The StoryMap used the Gaussian membership to select their slope range, but did not specify a spread. I also came across the Near membership, but that is similar enough to Gaussian that I am having the same issue of selecting the correct spread.
I think my midpoint should be 8, but I don't know which spread to use in order to capture down to zero and up to 16 with a member designation (1), and anything outside of that range as a non-member (0). Any suggestions on what I should set it as or a resource on how to interpret the spread number (0.01-1)?
Is there another member class that would fit my needs better?
